# Error when using export_inference_graph: TypeError: export_inference_graph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_side_inputs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm currently training an Object-Detection Model. Everything worked out well until I wanted to export my graph.

When I'm running the command

```
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-1606 --output_directory new_graph
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "export_inference_graph.py", line 206, in <module>
    tf.app.run()

  File "C:\Users\dm\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)

  File "C:\Users\dm\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)

  File "C:\Users\dm\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))

  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 202, in main
    side_input_types=side_input_types)

TypeError: export_inference_graph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_side_inputs'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong at this step? I'm using Python Python 3.7 in order to use Tensorflow 1.15.4. It's just very confusing because I was following a tutorial and everything until this point was completley fine. I would be very grateful, if someone knows how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8711)

> I somehow managed to get passed it. I'm thinking that the files we
> have are not compatible anymore. Some are updated while some are not.
> So I downloaded a very old version of the export_inference_graph.py
> from here:
>
> https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md
>
> And here are the codes to type instead:

```
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor
--pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config 
--checkpoint_path training/model.ckpt-1606
--inference_graph_path output_inference_graph.pb
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works, but I don't understand why the files aren't compatible anymore? Do you now the reason, why in my case it didn't work, but - as it seems - in most other cases does?

Comment: In comments section of issue there is an assumption that you use old version of sources. Make sure if you are using top of the tree (latest commit). If this solution helped please mark it as accepted answer.